# Auto Update of application using HockeyApp SDK

Tags: android

I am using Android HockeyAppSDK to deploy updates to an application. I am trying to use the [docs](http://support.hockeyapp.net/kb/client-integration-android/customization-options-for-android) to customise the default `UpdateManager` class to allow updates to be installed automatically, without prompting the user to accept the update.

I am quite unsure of how to handle this. The obvious way (in my mind anyway) is to do the following:

```
private void checkForUpdates () {

    UpdateManager.register (this, Constants.HOCKEY_API_KEY, new UpdateManagerListener() {

        public void onUpdateAvailable() {
           //I assume stuff will need to be handled here    
         }
    });     
}
```

Has anyone done this before, or can find a way to do it?

Many thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

After emailing the support team for Hockey, they believe that within their current compiled API it is not possible to perform an update without prompting users to accept.

The whole source would require modification and compilation before working as expected it seems.

Comment: HockeyApp SDK for Android has `isDialogRequired` flag but it seems doesn't allow to update the app without a notification.

Answer (score 0):

You can use UpdateTask from library

Comment: Can you provide sample code for how this could be done?